# Replace pannable world map image by Google Earth globe in Kinect sample

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, google-earth, kinect-sdk

I need basic guidance on how to control Google Earth using Kinect Hand gestures instead of using mouse/keyboard navigation.

I have ran Kinect Developer toolkit sample, and there is one named interactive gallery in C# that allows panning world map (It's a static image). Here is the link to it's documentation,
[Kinect interactive gallery](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=262371)

I exactly want to create the same thing but allowing the world globe to be moved,zoom and rotate using hand gestures instead of a simple map image.

Currently I ran Google Earth in WPF application using a  google earth plugin and using it via web browser component. here is the code,

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string PLUGIN_URL = @"http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/desktop-embedded/pluginhost.html";
        Uri url = new Uri(PLUGIN_URL);
        this.browser.Navigate(url);

       // this.browser.ObjectForScripting = this;



    }
}
```

I have also tried controlling it by controlling mouse cursor using Kinect but it is not providing good user experience.

I would like to add grip gesture to pan the globe. I went through the kinect samples code, the documentation is not very good and I don't know where the grip gesture is being handled and corresponding event is fired.

Here is WorldMap.xaml code that displays world map image:

```
`<PannableContentModel xmlns="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.InteractionGallery.Models;assembly=InteractionGallery-WPF" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<PannableContentModel.ImageUri>
    <x:Uri>pack://application:,,,/Content/PannableContentScreen/PannableMapImage.jpg</x:Uri>
</PannableContentModel.ImageUri>
```

`
I would like to display a Google earth globe instead.

Any help will be appreciated!